# TypoScript CONTENT select: always returns translated page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

please help me debug the following issue.
My goal is to select (from TypoScript) the default translation of a page, when visiting the same page in one of its non-default translations. The issue is that I always get back the translated version, despite the fact that the select where explicitly contains the language uid I need.
I use TYPO3 v11.5.19, my related TypoScript code is as follows:

```
defaultLangPageTitle = CONTENT
defaultLangPageTitle {
    table = pages
    select {
      pidInList.field = pid
      where = (sys_language_uid = 0 AND uid = {field:l10n_parent})
          where.insertData = 1
      languageField = 0
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = title
        wrap = <div id="en_title">|</div>
    }
}
```

My expectation was that languageField = 0 will disable translation and I will get the default lang title of the page.
But the result here is that the title of the page is displayed translated to the language of the displayed page.
I also tried to specify an exact uid of the original default lang page record (like 143) in the select, but the result is the same.
I did some checks and I changed renderObj to output the uid instead of the title and I saw that the uid itself is correct, so the page gets queried correctly, but anyways, when I ask to display the title, it shows up translated.

Can you please help what else I could try or what mistake did I do with the above?
Thanks a lot for your time & help in advance!